# Asp.Net Core app hosted in IIS - how to pass startup parameter

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I have a Asp.Net Core application wich can be hosted in IIS or as a WindowsService.

Here is part of a Program.cs

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hostAsWindowsService = !args.Contains("--web");

        var contentRoot = hostAsWindowsService ? Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) : Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(contentRoot)
            .AddJsonFile("host.json")
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        var environment = config["environment"];
        var urls = config["server.urls"];
        var certificateFilename = config["certificate.filename"];
        var certificatePassword = config["certificate.password"];

        var hostConfig = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseUrls(urls)
            .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
            .UseKestrel(options =>
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(certificateFilename))
                            {

                                options.UseHttps(contentRoot + certificateFilename, certificatePassword);
                            }
                        })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(environment))
        {
            hostConfig.UseEnvironment(environment);
        }

        if (hostAsWindowsService)
        {
            hostConfig
                .Build()
                .RunAsEycService();
        }
        else
        {
            hostConfig
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .Build()
                .Run();
        }
    }
}
```

I can not pass a parameter while hosted as a Windows Service so by default the project is hosted as WS. Can I actually pass a parameter to IIS while it starts my Site so the proper hosting inside Main method is used (args.Contains("--web"))?

I tried to pass parameters to Windows Service host:

1) sc.exe create MyService binPath= "c:\Projects\MyService.exe --ws=true"

2) by adding "--ws=true" to "Start parameters" in Windows Service dialog (it actually won't save)

Comment: How? I tried, but it did not work for me?

Comment: For Windows service https://stackoverflow.com/a/42828366/1544886

Comment: did you end up figuring out how to pass a parameter? Need some help over here...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question - but just in case someone else runs into this issue (like I just did).

- Go to the site in IIS Manager
- Open "Configuration Editor"
- In the "Section" dropdown, under "system.webServer", click "aspNetCore".
- In the "From" dropdown select "ApplicationHost.config <location path='your-site-name' />"
- You can now enter the command line arguments under "arguments".

Note that by using "ApplicationHost.config" rather than "your-site Web.config", you get to keep the setting even after re-publishing your site (overwriting the web.config file)